# Hashing an image (series of rgb bytes)

Tags: c++, winapi, hash

i'm developing an application that involves *screen capture and hashing* with C/C++. The image i'm capturing is about **250x250** in dimensions and i'm using the winapi **[HashData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** function for hashing.

*My goal is to compare 2 hashes (etc. 2 images of 250x250) and instantly tell if they're equal.*

My code:

```
           const int PIXEL_SIZE = (sc_part.height * sc_part.width)*3;
           BYTE* pixels = new BYTE[PIXEL_SIZE];
           for(UINT y=0,b=0;y<sc_part.height;y++) {
              for(UINT x=0;x<sc_part.width;x++) {
                 COLORREF rgb = sc_part.pixels[(y*sc_part.width)+x];
                 pixels[b++] = GetRValue(rgb);
                 pixels[b++] = GetGValue(rgb);
                 pixels[b++] = GetBValue(rgb);
              }
           }
           const int MAX_HASH_LEN = 64;
           BYTE Hash[MAX_HASH_LEN] = {0};
           HashData(pixels,PIXEL_SIZE,Hash,MAX_HASH_LEN);

           ... i have now my variable-size hash, above example uses 64 bytes

           delete[] pixels;
```

I've tested different hash sizes and their ~time for completion, which was roughly about:

```
           32 bytes  = ~30ms
           64 bytes  = ~47ms
           128 bytes = ~65ms
           256 bytes = ~125ms
```

My question is:

**How long should the hash code be for a 250x250 image to prevent any duplicates, like never?**

I don't like a hash code of *256* characters, since it will cause my app to run slowly (since the captures are very frequent). Is there a `"safe"` hash size per dimensions of image for comparing?

thanx

Comment: You can't have never.  The maths is very simple though; for a "good" hash function, the chance of two colliding is 1/2^(bits_in_hash).

Comment: Thanx for the comment. With "never" i actually meant quite infrequently, given the sized image dimension (which its not small and the quality differs in between images). Can you make an example of the chance formula above, didnt got it entirely.

Comment: This way, you can only tell that if the hashes differ, the images are not *exactly* the same. If the hashes are equal, you can not be sure that the images are too. You'll probably have to check them completely.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis, thanx for the comment. Yes, probably this isn't enough, but checking pixel-by-pixel would kill the performance since the updates are very frequent, almost real time (~70ms). I was wondering if i can trade "checking" quality for speed. How's possible is, say, a 256-byte hash, which is very big, to be completely equal with another, very different image? In my mind this will be very, very little, almost non-existant. Or am i missing something here? i mean, images are all different. But thanx, i'm going to do some tests.

Comment: What would happen if you *did* get a collision, and treat two frames as equal when they weren't?

Comment: @EricBrown, what i need to know is the percentage of computing a completely equal hash, using 2 (two) really different images. In your question, if i get a collision from two different images in *human-noticing* time period, i'm going to re-consider the way the hashing is done and change to other methods. I mostly need a way to shrink a 250x250 image into database-query friendly search criterion.

Comment: Since you're making a second copy of the image data before hashing it, you're probably not actually getting an actual improvement in performance. With you're doing now your copy operation reads 250,000 bytes and then writes 187,500 bytes then the hash function reads another 187,500 bytes. If you just compared the images directly without copying you'd be reading 250,000 bytes twice and not writing anything. You should hash the image data directly without copying, but you'll need to use a different hash function do this.

Comment: Also what exactly are you doing? Comparing one image with a bunch of other images to see if any of the other images are the same as the one image? Or comparing a bunch of images to see if any are the same? This make a huge difference in the probabilities.

Comment: @RossRidge, i'm actually getting a hash on-the-fly (desktop image), then using this hash i'm querying the database to find the entry containing the hash (a table of hashes, each one per image saved previously). And this needs to be done really fast. Of course the above code is not optimized (loop) since my main problem is to somehow "shrink" the image to actually fit in a database column, which must be also unique.

Comment: Ok, that means my comment about performance doesn't apply. It assumed you were comparing each captured image with only one fixed image. Things are much difference if you're comparing the captured images with themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, based on your comments, that you're adding the hash calculated "on-the-fly" to the database, and so the hash of every image in the database ends up getting compared to the hash of every other image in the database then you've run into the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). The likelihood that there are two identical numbers in a set of randomly selected numbers (eg. the birthdays of group of people) is greater than what you'd intuitively assume. If there are 23 people in a room then there's a 50:50 chance two of them share the same birthday.

That means assuming a good hash function then you can expect a collision, two images having the same hash despite not being identical, after 2^(N/2) hashes, where N is the number bits in the hash.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem) If your hash function isn't so good you can expect a collision even earlier. Unfortunately only Microsoft knows how good `HashData` actually is.

Your commments also bring up a couple of other issues. One is that `HashData` doesn't produce variable sized hashes. It produces an array of bytes that's always the same length as the value you passed as the hash length. Your problem is that you're treating it instead as a string of characters. In C++ strings are zero terminated, meaning that the end of string is marked with a zero valued character (`'\0'`). Since the array of bytes will contain 0 valued elements at random positions it will appear to be truncated when used a string. Treating the hash a string like this will make it much more likely that you'll get a collision.

The other issue is that you said that you stored the images being compared in your database and that these images must be unique. If this uniqueness is being enforced by the database then checking for uniqueness in your own code is redundant. Your database might very well be able to do this faster than your own code.

Comment: didn't thought about the zero-character terminator in hash :) but you're probably right in this. That is because i'm using mysql and in my *mysql_real_escape_string()* implementation there's a strlen() that counts the string; therefore it stop counts at first zero... Thanx for catching it. About the uniqueness, i already set my column as UNIQUE so the insertion is avoided if the hash given to query for insertion exists already in database. It seems the problem was that zero-terminated issue. My next step is to swap all zeros with, etc, 1, in the hash and go from there. Thanx.

Comment: @vlzvl Rather than trying to swap nulls, use Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

GUIDs (Globally Unique IDs) are 16 bytes long, and Microsoft assumes that no GUIDs will ever collide.

Using a 32 byte hash is equivalent to taking two randomly generated GUIDs and comparing them against two other randomly generated GUIDs.

The odds are vanishingly small (1/2^256) or  1.15792089E-77 that you will get a collision with a 32 byte hash.

The universe will reach heat death long before you get a collision.

[This comment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/19/134937.aspx#140095) from Michael Grier more or less encapsulates my beliefs.  In the worst case, you should take an image, compute a hash, change the image by 1 byte, and recompute the hash.  A good hash should change by more than one byte.

You also need to trade this off against the "birthday effect" (aka the pigeonhole principle) - any hash will generate collisions.   A quick comparison of the first N bytes, though, will typically reject collisions.

Cryptographic hashes are typically "better" hashes in the sense that more hash bits change per input bit change, but are much slower to compute.

Comment: Note that GUIDs are not hash values. There is a date and time component which helps making them (almost) unique. That is not nearly the same as hashing existing data. The odds are not nearly as small as you say, if the hash function is not done properly.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis True, GUIDs aren't pure hashes.  But the hash input is of fixed size, and even a 1e-40 failure case is likely not to happen within the lifespan of the universe.   So if the failure case is of low consequence (i.e., not life-threatening), I'd just ignore the epsilon probability of failure.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. But aren't the GUIDs purely created in random and not based on input? My hash code uses the image as an input but i'm not entirely sure how *"much"* of the image in whole is taking for compute it. It seems the *HashData* function produces variable hash sizes, which i don't know why since i tell it to produce 192 characters, and of course i fear for duplicates only in this case. There are many cases it produces less than half of it; i even found a random hash of 42 bytes. Perhaps a hash isn't a good candicate for lots of input like an image, even when the hash size is big?

Comment: @vlzvl added more detail to the answer.  I'm pretty sure that `HashData` uses all the input; it would be a pretty bad hash if it didn't.  Again, what's the real consequence of a collision?  What do you do after the database query?

Comment: @EricBrown, in case of collisions the user gets the first entry (in database) that hash meets the one asked for (in-the-fly). If there are 2 same hashes in database, since i'm making a query with LIMIT 1 clause, the system retrieves the first hash that fits, which might be the wrong one, thus giving the user the wrong image (in short). I also think that *HashData* can't be bad :) but that variable-sized hashes it produces are causing me a headache. I even found a hash of 5 characters once. I'm wondering if there's a problem with my code or *HashData* can indeed return sush smallish hash.